twilio sip registraion - BE node, FE react native (Twilio Register SIP Endpoint)
I have configured twilio SIP domain, TwiML app and credentials list for users.
But I am unable to register users in Registered SIP endpoints. Is it possible to register from react-native app?
I am using twilio voice-sdk and register method works fine with the generated token but still no new registered SIP endpoint appears on twilio console.
Is it even possible to register SIP endpoint from react-native app? Since I have tried a lot of packages like https://www.npmjs.com/package/@toandn96/react-native-pjsip and https://github.com/florindumitru/react-native-sip. But all of these packages are not maintained and have issues regarding Pods while building.
Have someone done it before? Please guide, thanks.

Twilio Support Engineer here. Please note, our Voice SDK products (iOS, Android, JavaScript and React Native) are a seperate offering from our Programmable Voice SIP Domain product. When you call the register method from within our SDK code, the client is registering itself for incoming calls but this registration is separate to a SIP client sending a SIP REGISTER to our SIP Domain product.
Currently, there isn't a way to see active registrations in the Console for SDK clients.
